# How to load more data in ng-repeat if there's not enough?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, pagination

I have a filter in ng-repeat and ng-if condition and there almost always will be less then 10 results per page (10 results is what I get from API).

My idea is that in js file should be a cycle with condition

First we declare variable so we can check the length

````
           var numberOfArticlesOnPage = container.children.length
           console.log(numberOfArticlesOnPage)

           for (i = 0; numberOfArticlesOnPage < 10); i++ {
               $scope.pageNumber = $scope.pageNumber + 1
               var i=1
               i++
               $http(
                   {
                       method: 'GET',
                       url: 

//Here I put i instead of page number so it loads next page and every time we create results[i] with new number in the end

'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?fq=news_desk:("Politics")&page=' + i + '&api-key=groQeNemKAhk7QjDWircgauo5jYVcwez', /* Most recent */
                   }).then(function successCallback(result) {
                       $scope.results[i] = result.data.response.docs;
                   }, function errorCallback(result) {
                       console.log("there's a error, man...");
                   });
                //Check the length again
                   var container = document.querySelector(".container");
                   var numberOfArticlesOnPage = container.children.length```

//And that is the template where it should be shown

```<div class="container">
           <div class="box" ng-repeat="result in results | filter : '!trump'" ng-if="result.multimedia[2].url != null">
               <h2>{{result.headline.main}}</h2>
               <p class="abstract">{{result.abstract}}</p>
               <img src="https://static01.nyt.com/{{result.multimedia[0].url}}">
               <p></p>
               <a ui-sref="article ({
               articleSlug:'{{result.headline.main | slugify}}', 
               title: '{{result.headline.main}}',
               url: '{{result.web_url}}', 
               image: 'https://static01.nyt.com/{{result.multimedia[0].url}}',
               externalUrl: '{{result.url}}'
               })">Read more...</a>
           </div>
       </div>```


//But I don't know how to write a code in the template so it can take more data?
````

Comment: ng-mess... if your doing pagination and that data is coming from the server and you want more then basic next/back you must do all the the sorting filtering serverside or your get unexpected results

Comment: I do actually want basic next/back :)
This is should be some simple website

Comment: sure, but you must use the filtering the api provides: https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/articlesearch-product/1/overview i.e trump should be passed to `?fq=news_desk:("Politics") AND body:(YOURFILTER)` else if you filter out clientside it wont magically run that filter serverside and show only them result it will only filter on your local which trump might not be on that page or he will be on all resulting in not results. get me

Comment: Lawrence Cherone, you are awesome :D thanks. That works